# How did Binance Exchange get hacked in April of 2019 (7000 BTC) and how much is in the SAFU insurance fund?

Tags: exchanges, binance, hack

Binance exchange got hacked in April 2019 for 7000 BTC (50 Million USD), but how did it get hacked exactly? They say they are going to pay everyone back via their SAFU insurance fund, but how much is in that SAFU account?

Comment: I think you'll need to ask Binance; I doubt anyone here can answer questions about their internal operations.